# Getting and Displaying AD object properties via a webform

Tags: asp.net

What would be the easiest way to get AD user object properties via a webform based on user input?
To elaborate a bit more this is what I would need:

1. User enters input to an input field (Employee number - we store it as an extension attribute in AD)
2. On button click the form returns additional user object properties of the account (such as sAMAccountname, Manager) and displays it on the page (preferably)

I also need to have these properties converted to variables the form can use to pass on to another page sending an e-mail with the retrieved information.

We're using asp for our webforms. So far we only needed to pass user input directly to the mail sender, but this one seems more tricky.

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

    if(user != null)
    {
       // display the various properties of the "user" object in your web page
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!